# How To return Name and Email from ASP.NET in JSON format

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, json, web-services

i need to return the names and emails which are selected from a MS SQL 2008 table in a JSON format. here is what I've got so far :

```
public class RaumHelper
{
    internal static string[] Raum()
    {
        List<string> raumObject = new List<string>();

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=Localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=BOOK-IT-V2;Integrated Security=true;"))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT NAME, EMAIL FROM RAUM", con))
        {
            con.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    if (rdr["NAME"] != DBNull.Value && rdr["EMAIL"] != DBNull.Value)
                    {
                        raumObject.Add(rdr["NAME"].ToString());
                        raumObject.Add(rdr["EMAIL"].ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return raumObject.ToArray();
    }
}
```

i want to return it in json format not Array.

it should look like this or similar:

```
 {"d":[{
  "Name": "Hans",
  "Email": "bla@blub.de"
  }]}
```

Answer (score 4):

You JavaScriptSerializer class to convert list object into json format

```
string JSonString = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(raumObject).ToString()
```

Comment: how can i set a key to my results? Name:Hans

Answer (score 2):

use the [JavascriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) Serialize function or another serializer like [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/)

EDIT:

with `JavascriptSerializer`:

```
new JavascriptSerializer().Serialize(new{d=raumObject.ToArray()});
```

EDIT 2:

To have keys for your values do not store your values in a List:

```
internal static string[] Raum()
{
    List<object> raumObject = new List<object>();

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=Localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=BOOK-IT-V2;Integrated Security=true;"))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT NAME, EMAIL FROM RAUM", con))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                if (rdr["NAME"] != DBNull.Value && rdr["EMAIL"] != DBNull.Value)
                {
                    raumObject.Add(new{
                         Name=rdr["NAME"].ToString(),
                         Email=rdr["EMAIL"].ToString()
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return  new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new{d=raumObject.ToArray()});
}
```

Comment: but how can i give a key to the values?